# 3 Monitors via Crossfire x2 graphic cards

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have previously been using a USB 3.0 to support my 3rd monitor, but my Dell monitor only supports 1080 on HDMI annoyingly.

I have tried every combination I can think of on my 2 separate graphic cards to get the 3 monitors working together.

My monitors are 30" 2560x1600 and 2 27" with a resolution of 2560x1440.

So I have the 30 on a DVI > HDMI converter the other 2 are just on DVI > DVI, so no conversation.

How can you get monitors working over the 2 separate graphic cards? I thought it would just be plug and play?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wierd. I know 3 displays on 2 cards is an option I did that across a nvidia adaptor and an onboard intel adaptor. That you're using 'SLI' is odd tho, considering its AMD. Do you mean crossfire? What happens when you turn off SLI/crossfire? Also what exactly are these cards?

Comment: I do indeed mean crossfire :) Turning it off did nothing unfortunately.

Comment: What graphics cards do you have?

Comment: Oh yes, I should have said. 2x R9 289x

Comment: Did you mean R9 280x or R9 290x? Though, admittedly, either one should support at least 3 displays. Might be worth [edit]ing the model into your question, as well.

Comment: 280x sapphire branding. Oddly when I boot I see two windows logos on the central and right monitors but when the PC boots up it's using the left and right monitors. Also worth noting I am using the beta drivers

Comment: Which card is which monitor connected to?

Answer (score 0):

[It seems](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7400/the-radeon-r9-280x-review-feat-asus-xfx/3) you'll need identical monitors to run all three off of TMDS-clocked interfaces (i.e. DVI or HDMI).

> The catch here is that these can’t be independent displays, and this change is primarily intended towards enabling Eyefinity with cheap, DVI/HDMI-only monitors. To utilize clock sharing and to drive 3 such monitors off of a single card, **all 3 monitors must be timing-identical**, which functionally speaking almost always requires the monitors to be completely identical. Furthermore the sharing of the clock generator can only be engaged/disabled upon boot, so the 3rd display cannot be hot-plugged and must be present at boot time.

(Emphasis Anandtech's)

An *active* (not passive) DisplayPort to DVI/HDMI adaptor will allow you to use the displays you currently have:

> Using the DisplayPort, either with a native monitor or through an active DP-to-DVI/HDMI adapter, still allows the same fully independent functionality as before.

Comment: Or to put it more simply, to run three monitors off an AMD card at least one of them has to be connected via native DisplayPort.